# Web bowser automation alternatives after IE11 is discontinued?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, com, internet-explorer-11, browser-automation

Over the last 10 years I have build a few business critical IE11 automation tools that use the COM object of Internet Explorer to automate laborious tasks.

Specifically tasks such as page navigation for web scraping purposes; as well JavaScript execution for automating business processes.

With IE11 being discontinued soon, what are the alternative options to web browser automation?

I have code written in VBA, vbscript, and PowerShell

Comment: You can do a lot with Invoke-Webrequest (even when you use the basicparsing switch). Personally I've never seen the need to use an IE COM object since you can manipulate headers, get the content, set cookies etc all from the webrequests. Fiddler is however your best friend when taking this approach.

Comment: If you think that Microsoft web driver can help to automate the browser then I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer. To accept the answer, click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in. Ref: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the [Microsoft Web driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) and try to automate the [MS Edge (Chromium)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) browser.

It supports many developing languages such as C#, Ruby, Java, Python, and JS. [See here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

There are many advantages to automate the MS Edge (Chromium) browser.

If your clients are having the legacy websites that can only work with the IE browser then there is an **IE mode** available in the MS Edge (Chromium) browser and you can also automate that IE mode.

Scroll to the [Automating Internet Explorer mode](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/11/04/edge-chromium-release-candidate-get-ready/) point

So I think that this can be the suitable choice to automate the browser.

Comment: this is not equivalent, the Web Driver requires constant updating to match the version of the web browser so any VB code will break every time the browser is updated a few versions, which it is constantly due to security patches